# Unable to assign C# property to SVG textPath in a .razor file

Tags: c#, svg, razor, blazor

I have been wrapping text around a circle SVG circle, but when i assign the text to a C# property it wont show.

The following code works without any issue -

```
        <svg>
            <path id="circle" d="m96.06557,140.16394c-27.62431,0 -50,-22.37569 -50,-50c0,-27.62431 22.37569,-50 50,-50c27.62431,0 48.85246,22.37569 48.85246,50c0,27.62431 -21.22815,50 -48.85246,50z" />
            <text transform="rotate(155 95.4918 90.1639)">
                <textPath xlink:href="#circle">
                    EXPECTED RESULT 
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </svg>
```

[This is the result of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B8fA.png)

But when change the "EXPECTED RESULT" text to a C# property (@text)...

```
         <svg>
            <path id="circle" d="m96.06557,140.16394c-27.62431,0 -50,-22.37569 -50,-50c0,-27.62431 22.37569,-50 50,-50c27.62431,0 48.85246,22.37569 48.85246,50c0,27.62431 -21.22815,50 -48.85246,50z" />
            <text transform="rotate(155 95.4918 90.1639)">
                <textPath xlink:href="#circle">
                    @text
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </svg>
```

[I get no text at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiPGW.png)

Code example - https://blazorfiddle.com/s/7at03xjw

So to summarize my question - **how do i assign a C# object to a SVG path in a .razor file?**

Comment: This looks similar, but oddly, their code _does_ work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68008743/blazor-svg-real-time-updates

Comment: If you look at the DOM after `@text` is updated, then the `<textPath>` element does actually contain the updated text, but the browser isn't updating or re-rendering the SVG image, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with using `xlink:href`. Change it to `href` and you'll be golden.

Refer to the Mozilla documentation regarding deprecation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href

BlazorFiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/9smd12u2

Comment: Spent *hours* trying to get `<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="@SVG">` to work, where `@SVG` was set to `#people-1`. Worked fine when the icon was hardcoded (i.e. `<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#people-1">`) but broke when using a variable. I am quite shocked that they haven't made Blazor / Razor compatible with standard HTML markup for things like this. Using `href`, without `xmlns:link`, worked a treat.